# Problems with Dapp Development with Flutter and web3

Tags: flutter, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, flutter-web3

I need to clarify a doubt in the development of Dapp, when creating a mobile app with flutter can I use web3 to connect with the wallet and the blockchain?

Answer (score 3):

**[Edit 2021-12-02]** I just found this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web3, it is web only but seems to be compatible with WalletConnect QR codes connection, so it is probably worth a try.

**Original answer:**

I believe you can check out [flutter_web3_provider](https://github.com/gochain/flutter_web3_provider) but it only works for web.

I believe you can also use [WalletConnect](https://docs.walletconnect.org/) to support mobile wallets like [these ones](https://registry.walletconnect.org/wallets), but I haven't found a wrapper/implementation for flutter so you would need to implement that. But the good news is you would be able to use it in native apps. I see there is a react-native implementation so hopefully somebody will write the flutter implementation soon. You can support/like the request [here](https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/issues/540).

Also you can directly sign and send transactions to an RPC server (a more direct gate to the blockchain) using [web3dart](https://github.com/simolus3/web3dart#connecting-to-an-rpc-server), but of course you would need to ask for and/or store the user's private key, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: https://giters.com/Orange-Wallet/wallet-connect-dart It looks like here we have Dart implementation.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilovus sorry, I believe that implementation is building a wallet app themselves, not for dapps that want to connect to a wallet.

Comment: There is now [walletconnect_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart) package which also supports connecting to Wallets and sending requests to the Wallets.